# Hyper parameters of Beta distribution

Tags: probability, self-study, beta-distribution

> Suppose $\theta \sim \beta(\alpha_1, \alpha_2)$ and we believe that
>   $E[\theta] = m$ and $p(l < \theta < u) = 0.95$. Write a program that
>   can solve for $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ in terms of $m$, $l$ and $u$.
>   Hint: write $\alpha_2$ as a function of $\alpha_1$ and $m$, so the pdf
>   only has one unknown; then write down the probability mass contained
>   in the interval as an integral, and minimize its squared discrepancy
>   from $0.95$. What values do you get if $m = 0.15$, $l = 0.05$ and $u =0.3$? What is the equivalent sample size of this prior?

I was able to get an expression for $\alpha_2$ in terms of $\alpha_1$ and $m$. Also I was able to express $p(l < \theta < u)$ as the difference of the cdf of beta for $u$ and $l$. But after that how do I integrate that to get $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ in terms of $m$, $l$, $u$?

Comment: Why don't you just use a numerical solver?

Comment: @NeilG How do I construct the problem?

Comment: Just copy the constraints.  Have you ever used a numerical solver?  http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html   You want a "scalar root finder".

Comment: @NeilG No I have not.

Comment: Cool, should be maybe five to ten lines of code to solve your problem.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

So you get $f$ such that $\alpha_2=f(\alpha_1,m)$. You know $u$, $l$ and $m$. Then you just have to cancel:
$$
g(\alpha_1) =(p(l<θ<u ; \alpha_1,f(\alpha_1,m))-0.95)
$$
where $p(l<θ<u ; \alpha_1,f(\alpha_1,m))$ is obtained from your differences of the cdf of beta. This cancelation over $\alpha_1$ can be achieved using a root finder (in the language you desire).

Comment: Using a minimizer is really roundabout.  The minimizer essentially computes a gradient (either directly or by differences), which are then passed to a root-finder.   You might as well use a root-finder directly.

Comment: @Neil G Agreed. I edited. thks for the input

Comment: @peuhp i did not understand what you meant by "cancellation". I want $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ in terms of m, l and u. Would a root finder give me the desired expression?

Comment: Well,  the $\alpha_1$ satisfying $g(\alpha_1)=0$ is the one your expect. Then maybe you can look for a close form formula : try to cancel the derivative of $g$ analytically but It seems that your question (write a program) suggests to make it numerically. Once $\alpha_1$ is obtained, $\alpha_2$ comes from $f$ as a function of $m$ and $\alpha_1$. Hope it helps.